# Is the Cospox a plothole?

Tags: danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony

Tsumigi Shirogane the ultimate cosplayer says she can't cosplay "real" people (Kaede) without getting the cospox in chapter 1. Over to chapter 6 with all the 4th wall breaks, and she's cosplaying as other (presumably fictional) people with no pink cospox issues.

So did she just fake the cospox in chapter 1? Or is Kaede real and everyone else fictional?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible explanation for this.

- As you've said it yourself, she's cosplaying as ***presumably fictional*** characters. These aren't real, thus her Cospox doesn't trigger. Following conclusions are possible:

  - Danganronpa 1 and 2 were video games before the series eventually became a reality TV show up to V3. Reality TV characters would be considered real, while video game characters wouldn't.
  - Tsumugi considers the characters of V3 to be real people, since that's the reality they've created. Characters from other Danganronpa installments, meanwhile, are no longer real, as their "reality" has already ended.
- Tsumugi lied, and the Cospox is actually part of her cosplay. Remember that she can instantly transform into any character. She could've easily pretended Cospox existed, by taking her time changing into Kaede's clothes, while instantly changing her skin's color using her Ultimate Cosplayer ability.

  She probably invented Cospox to help solve the first case, as it would make for a very boring show, if the class lost during the first Trial. The purpose of these shows are to spread despair, after all. Watching the class slowly fall apart as more and more people die, is much more effective in that respect.

In either case, Tsumugi — being the mastermind behind V3 — had been lying from the very beginning. It should be assumed that not everything she says can be taken at face value. Not even her "condition".